# "Elasticsearch:UserIllegalArgumentException" on app that was working before

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, elasticsearch, aws-appsync

I have an app published on Android that was working perfectly, one day just stopped working, debugging the code I got this error on elastic search query:
`"Elasticsearch:UserIllegalArgumentException"`

Any clue? I think this is something related to AWS Admin Page Settings but not sure, I don't know what can I do.

Notes:
The React Native code has not been updated.
The app was working everyday and stopped to work without touch the code, so the error should be something related to AWS, I don't know :s

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your index was deleted. You can check that by going to your [esv3 dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/esv3/home), click on "domains" and then click on the domain in question. Then find the "indices" tab and see if the index you're using is there. If not, you'll need to recreate it and its data.